# Zf2 Loading a custom class in project

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm new to the Zend Framework. I added a bunch of API classes for Google Calendar to the */vendor/* folder. Then I wrote a custom class for authenticating and adding an event to my Google Calendar account. And placed it in */module/Application/src/Application/Util/GoogleAgenda.php*

So. Now in the *EventController* (in *module/Event/src/Event/EventController.php*) I would like to use the custom *GoogleAgenda* class with something like this:

```
    $agenda = new \GoogleAgenda();
    if($agenda->auth()) {
        $success = $agenda->addEvent($event->serviceName, "", $event->locationName, "2014-02-27T17:00:00.000+00:00", "2014-02-27T18:00:00.000+00:00");
        if(!$success) {
            die("Google Calendar Api - Failed to add event");
        }
    }
```

This gives the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'GoogleAgenda' not found in EventController.php on
>   line 60

So, where to put my custom *GoogleAgenda* class? And how to load them from a controller class in another module.

I thought my Util folder was a good place to store this class. Because it is a util class that I would like to use in the entire application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the class to be autoloaded. Since you've put it in your application module, It's easiest for you that module's namespace and autoloader setup. Since the class lives at `module/Application/src/Application/Util/GoogleAgenda.php`, it's declaration should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Util;

class GoogleAgenda
{
    [...]
}
```

and usage for it would be:

```
$agenda = new \Application\Util\GoogleAgenda();
```

or, a little nicer:

```
use Application\Util\GoogleAgenda;

[...]

$agenda = new GoogleAgenda();
```

> And how to load them from a controller class in another module

The code above should work from any module in your app.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it works! I also noticed that I needed to add a "\" before calling classes that are in the vendor\google-api\ folder. Like $this->_client = new \GoogleClient(); Otherwise it was looking for that class in the new namespace Application\Util. Cheers!

Comment: Yup, or add a `use GoogleClient` to the top of the PHP script like in my example above.